# How to redirect the application to home page when refreshing the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a ReactJS application with two pages:

1 - Home Page, where the code requests characters data from Star Wars API (https://swapi.co/);

2 - Characters Page, where the characters data is showned, based on the data extracted from the API in the home page.

If I refresh the page when I'm in home page, that's ok. The data will be requested again. But if I'm in the characters page, it crashes because the characters page doesn't request any data. It works with data already collected in home page.

How can I redirect the user to home page if he or she reloads it in the characters page?

I'm using react-router-dom and the home page url is set as "/" and the characters page is "/characters".

I'm also using Redux to store the data.

Thanks.

Comment: history.push('/home'); use this to redirect on your required conditions

Comment: In your app.js or the first component that starts rendering, you can do history.push('/home') based on checks and conditions required for your app.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I added the [source code](https://github.com/ydhan18/stack-overflow-star-wars) for a React/Redux application example that uses `axios` and `redux-thunk` to get data from the API.

---

Are you using `connect()` from `react-redux` on your Characters Page component?

If not, you can do the following:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const CharactersPage = props => {
    // You can retrieve your data from props.characterData

    return ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { characterData: state.characterData }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CharactersPage)
```

This should solve the issue of your Characters Page crashing on reload because it doesn't have the data.

And if you really need to redirect users to the `/` page, you can utilize the `history` object. It automatically gets passed down when you set up your routes using `<Route>` from `react-router-dom`, given that you set up your route as such:

```
<Route path='/characters' component={CharactersPage} />
```

If you use `render={}` instead, you can get the `history` object by doing:

```
<Route path='/characters' render={routeProps => <CharactersPage {...routeProps} />} />
```

---

I hope this helps!

Comment: Connect would't help here on a page refresh.  He would have to store the data in localstorage or something and insert it into the initial state when the page is refreshed.  The issue he is having is that there is no data to connect to because of the refresh.

Comment: I used connect in Characters page and now it no longer crashes. Thanks! After some analisys, I concluded that, going back to home page wouldn't be a good practice from users perception. So I created a validation to fill the store again from characters page just if the store is empty, which means page was probably reloaded. If store isn't empty, the function I created returns false and a new request won't be needed. You guys are amazing. Thanks again.